# Ordinary Differential Equation - non-homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation I'm given is

$$\frac{d^2y}{d x^2} + \frac{4}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} = x$$

I'm given that $u(x)=y'(x)$ and have to convert it into first order ODE for $u$ which (with the help of fellow members) I got the answer to be $$u=\frac{1}{6}x^2+\frac{C}{x^{4}}$$ which I believe is correct.

Now it asks me to find the general solution of the equation obtained for $u$ and then use that to find the general solution of the first (original) equation. I'm stuggling to find on what to do next, do I need to find a particular integral and if so, which equation do I use?

[image]

Comment: Use the fact that you set $u=y' \implies u\,dx = dy$

Comment: This is a Cauchy-Euler equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$y'=u \implies y(x)=\int u(x) dx$$

here is another solution

$$y''+\frac 4xy'=x$$
multiply both side by $x^4$
$$x^4y''+4x^3y'=x^5$$
$$(x^4y')=\int x^5 dx$$
$$x^4y'=\frac 16 x^6+K_1$$
$$y'=\frac {K_1}{x^4}+\frac 16x^2$$
Integrate
$$y=\int \frac {K_1}{x^4}+\frac 16x^2dx$$
$$y(x)= \frac {C_1}{x^3}+\frac {x^3} {18}+C_2$$
With the initial conditions
$$(y(1),y'(1))=(1/18,1/2) \implies (C_1,C_2)=(-1/9,1/9)$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=-\frac 1{9x^3}+\frac {x^3} {18}+\frac 19}$$

Comment: If the initial conditions are y(1) = 1/18 and y'(1) = 1/2, are the two constants 1/3 and -1/3?

Comment: @JohnCamary I added a line

Comment: Shouldn't the C1/x^3 be negative?

Comment: @JohnCamary  if you have a minus sign in front of a constant then it absorb the minus sign $$-k_1x^3=C_1x^3$$ and I got $C_1=-1/9$

Comment: Another user has written the equation without the absorption of the minus sign, this will affect the outcome of the initial values, could you explain to me why?

Comment: @john he will get different value for his $c_1$ but in the end the equation is the same...$$-\frac {c_1}3=C_1 $$ his consant wil be equal to $$c_1=\frac 13$$

Comment: Could you also explain how you got c1= -1/9? by putting 1/2 = 1/6 + c1, I get c1= 1/3

Comment: @john you plug the value $y(1)=1/18$ which means that when $x=1 \implies y =1/18$ the same for $y'(1)=1/2$ it's a system of two equations

Comment: But you wrote 1/9 which I can't seem to get, I can only get c1= 1/3

Comment: use this equation $$y(x)= \frac {C_1}{x^3}+\frac {x^3} {18}+C_2$$ and plug $x=1$ and $y=1/18$

Comment: I get 1/18 = C1 + 1/18 + C2 so, C1 + C2 = 0

Comment: @JohnCamary thats good    now differenti=ate that equation $$y'(x)=-3C_1 \frac 1 {x^4}+\frac {x^2}{6}$$ since you  have that $x=1 \implies y'(1)=1/2$  and solve the system of equations

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the differential equation takes the form
$$\frac{1}{x^{4}} \, \frac{d}{dx} \left(x^{4} \, \frac{dy}{dx} \right) = x.$$
Now,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^{4}} \, \frac{d}{dx} \left(x^{4} \, \frac{dy}{dx} \right) &= x \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left(x^{4} \, \frac{dy}{dx} \right) &= x^5 \\
x^{4} \, y' &= \frac{x^{6}}{6} + c_{1} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{x^{2}}{6} + \frac{c_{1}}{x^{4}} \\
y(x) &= \frac{x^{3}}{18} - \frac{c_{1}}{3 \, x^{3}} + c_{0}.
\end{align}

Comment: If the initial conditions are y(1) = 1/18 and y'(1) = 1/2, are the two constants 1/3 and -1/3?